# Limit Conceptual Question 2

Tags: real-analysis, limits

If {$x_n$} is a monotone increasing sequence and {$x_n$} diverges. Does it imply that $lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{x_n}{x_{n+1}}$ converges? What about $\sum_{n\to\infty} \frac{x_n}{x_{n+1}}$. Proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Define a sequence $x_n$ by letting $x_1 = 1$, and $x_{n + 1} = 2 x_n$ for even values of $n$, and $x_{n + 1} = 3 x_n$ for odd values.

Comment: so no for the first part?

Comment: @user136266 No for the first part (and no for the second part as well: Do you see why?).